# Quel est l'antonyme de l'« incurie » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, antonyme

Quel est l'antonyme de l'[*incurie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/incurie) que l'on définit comme le *défaut de soin* ou *négligence* (Wiktionnaire) ? La réponse fonctionnerait avec la locution verbale [*faire preuve de*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_preuve), conjuguée dans une phrase complète avec un sujet usuel (*une personne*). C'est que j'ai l'impression que *soin*, *faire preuve de soin*, est relié [*soigné*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/soign%C3%A9) que j'associe moins à l'antonyme de négligence ; j'ai une hésitation sémantique. Est-ce qu'on la partage ou non et pourquoi ; quel antonyme choisit-on ?

Comment: Le Robert ne propose qu'un antonyme : *soin*, l'opposé de tout ce qui se trouve dans cette page richement fournie : https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/soin selon le contexte (l'incurie spécifique de la situation observée) des dérivés du mot soin ou différents antonymes peuvent convenir.

Comment: _Souci, préoccupation ; Occupation, responsabilité qu'une personne doit assume ; Actes de sollicitude ; Application_. (TLFi A, B, C, D). C'est peut-être en combinant avec l'idée de responsabilité qu'on dépasse la simple insouciance. Merci. @Personne

Answer (score 2):

Les antonymes proposés par les divers outils disponibles manquent d'intensité par rapport à ce qu'implique incurie. Il me semble donc qu'un adjectif est nécessaire pour le contrebalancer, par exemple :

> rigueur extrême / extrême rigueur.

> rigueur absolue

> soin extrême.

Comment: L'intensité en effet. Peut-être que la définition au Wiktionnaire était un peu timide et que c'est plutôt une négligence _grossière_... « Indifférence et manque total de soin ou d'application » (TLFi).

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que *sériosité*, *prudence*, *rigueur*, *assiduité* peuvent convenir, tout cela dépend du contexte et de la force avec laquelle on veut exprimer notre idée.

Comment: « sériosité » est rare : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9riosit%C3%A9

Comment: « Sériosité » inconnu dans la sphère académique https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/s%C3%A9riosit%C3%A9 … à moins d'être entouré de personnes qui ont l'art de déterrer avec sériosité les cadavres linguistiques en ignorant ***Le sérieux** : avoir l'esprit de sérieux, être pris au sérieux, manquer de sérieux* , donc ***avec le sérieux*** (sériosité)  qu'une charge impose … :-)

Comment: La combinaison de _prudence_ et de _rigueur_ est utile. Je comprends le besoin de contexte mais c'est vraiment un truc abstrait. Je dis assez souvent d'une personne qu'elle fait preuve d'incurie, et souvent j'ajoute _totale_. Je me demandais simplement comment j'exprimerais le contraire spontanément. Je me suis dit qu'ill était utile d'associer les deux côtés de la médaille, mais parfois avec la langue une médaille a plus de deux côtés...

Answer (score 0):

Tous les antonymes issus de cette [source](http://www.antonyme.org/antonyme/incurie) se combinent avec « faire preuve de ».

- circonspection,   concentration,    sérieux,    soin

Comment: Des sens de sérieux sont utiles (_réfléchi, digne de confiance_, etc.) , pourvu qu'on ne le voit pas comme _ne pas faire preuve de gaieté_. Aussi on peut faire preuve de sérieux avec une chose pas sérieuse du tout ; une chose peut ne pas requérir de s'en soucier sérieusement.